# Animated transform on child of parent with hidden overflow and border radius

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have seen various mentions of a bug involving `overflow:hidden` and `border-radius` in Chrome around the web but none seem to have a solution that works for me.

I've put the relevant code here: http://codepen.io/jolora/pen/MadgQm

The hover transition effect works fine in Safari and Firefox but bugs out in Canary (v49. Chrome v46 is working fine).

If I remove the `overflow:hidden` rule from .service the hover works as expected. I'm using a blur filter though so I need to clip the blur somehow - I don't want it bleeding out the edges of the parent.

Screenshots:

- Safari on hover (as it should look):
  [image]
- Canary on hover (the background of .service shows through in a square only during the transition period of 0.25s):
  [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What issue are you seeing and what should it look like? It looks alright to me in Chrome (not Canary)
With overflow:hidden -
[image]

Without overflow:hidden - 
[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. I've updated the question to include screenshots.

Comment: Removing overflow:hidden stops the brown box issue but then I'm left with the blur bleeding out of the .service container.

Comment: I've checked and it's a Canary-only problem it seems. Hopefully that means it's just a bug in Canary.